# Is it possible to make a gradient-transparent/layer masking image using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency, gradient

I've been following the lessons about transparency and gradients on the Mozilla site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors but I have not been able to figure this one out.

I know I can achieve these effects with a png image; however, in the program I am working on the gradient will change constantly according to where the image is moved.

Here's an example of the effect I'm looking for.
http://home.insightbb.com/~epyonxl1/gradientex.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've aded some code here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/canvasimagegradient/ that adds a **drawImageGradient** function to the CanvasRenderingContext2D. You can draw an image with a linear or radial gradient. It doesn't work in IE, even with excanvas, due to the lack of getImageData/putImageData support.

The following code for example will draw an image with a radial gradient (context retrieve and image load not shown):

```
var radGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    img.width / 2, img.height / 2, 10, 
    img.width / 2, img.height / 2, img.width/2);
radGrad.addColorStop(0, "transparent");
radGrad.addColorStop(1, "#000");

ctx.drawImageGradient(img, 112.5, 130, radGrad);
```

The code works as follows:

1. Create a canvas element dynamically and draw the image on it.
2. Retrieve the imageData for this new canvas.
3. Retrieve the imageData for the location on the canvas you want to draw the image on to.
4. Iterate through the destination imageData and update each pixel adding together a percentage (derived from the gradient transparency value) of the image and destination pixel values.
5. Finally put the updated image data back onto the destination canvas.

Obviously performance is an issue as images get larger. The image on https://code.google.com/archive/p/canvasimagegradient/ it takes about 6-10ms to draw. A 1024x768 image takes about 100ms-250ms to draw. Still usable though as long as you're not animating.

Comment: Ah, I knew after I forgot to specify I already know how to create a gradient such as this https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_9_canvas_lineargradient.html that I would get this answer. Unfortunately these only apply to specific colors. If its an image(non-solid color) on the other hand this method simply does not work.

Comment: I went back and took a look at the image and see what you want now. Good question. I'm thinking if you out the image in a seperate canvas and retrieve the image data you could apply a gradient affect to it and then overlay it over the original canvas. I'll have a play around and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Sounds good, won't have to much time over the weekend to work on it myself but I'll see what I come up with as well. Keep me posted on anything you figure out also. I definitely want to solve this thing.

Comment: I've got something working where an image can be overlayed on another image with semi-transparency. There's no gradient at the moment though, still working at it.

Comment: I've finally got this working. I just need to tidy the code before I post it.

Comment: Getting further than I am. I managed to get it work using the png image trick just to see if it would work but the furthest ive gotten doing it the *right* way is with just blending two images together no gradient-transparency.

Before your next post I just wanted to go ahead and thank you in advance for taking the time to help me out with this, much respect.

Comment: No problem. It's been fun just playing about. A good learning experience as well.

Comment: To accomplish the same without pixel-by-pixel manipulation, see @Alnitak's answer below.

Comment: @Nathan I downloaded this 10 year old (archived) repository and converted it to [a GitHub project](https://github.com/rmkane/canvas-image-gradient) that uses npm and webpack. I will try to incorporate Alnitak's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28779849/1762224) whenever I get the time.

Answer (score 24):

Its possible to use context.globalCompositeOperation to make the the mask

```
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0,0, img.width, img.height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, img.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fillRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

This do not do per pixel manipulation and should be faster

Comment: I agree this should be faster, and probably the correct answer.

Comment: As far as I can see, the reason that this is not the correct answer is that you're only using the gradient to impact a solid-color rectangle.  The OP asked about using a gradient to impact an image.

Comment: @Alnitak Your solution works to put a solid color over an image, but it does not work to put one image over another.  The example the OP linked to in the question itself shows one image over another, not just a solid color over an image.  I do not think this accomplishes the OP's goal.

Comment: Look at @Alnitak's awnsor for a better example of this method.

Answer (score 13):

To correctly merge two images using a transparency mask it's first necessary to take one of the two images and put it into an *off screen* canvas, and add the desired transparency mask using `context.globalCompositeOperation = destination-out` per @Tommyka's answer

```
var offscreen = document.createElement('canvas'); // detached from DOM
var context = offscreen.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.width, image1.height);

var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, img.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fillRect(0, 0, image1.width, image1.height);
```

Then, to actually merge the two images you then need to draw the other image into another canvas, and then simply draw the alpha-composited offscreen canvas on top of that:

```
var onscreen = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var context2 = onscreen.getContext('2d');
context2.drawImage(image2, 0, 0, image2.width, image2.height);
context2.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, onscreen.width, onscreen.height);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/rfdjoh31/4/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It works as well as @Castrohenge's solution but doesn't require (slow) pixel-by-pixel manipulation.  Thanks for it!

Comment: I added [my own implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283646/1762224) of the code seen above.

Comment: I don't see anything in the jsFiddle output when I click the run button - am I missing something?

Comment: @skunkwerk it looks like cross-origin protections in modern browsers are preventing the code in one frame from modifying the canvas in another (i.e. it's a jsFiddle issue)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make an image transparent set the `ctx.globalAlpha` to whatever you need (1, no transparency, is default).  Then reset it after you draw your image.  This URL probably will help as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing.

Answer (score 1):

I have modernized [Alnitak's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28779849/1762224) by incorporating asynchronous loading of the images.

I also got rid of magic numbers.

```js
const imageUrls = [
  // Base image
  'http://www.netstate.com/states/symb/flowers/images/apple_blossoms.jpg',
  // Gradient image
  'http://www.netstate.com/states/symb/flowers/images/oklahoma_rose.jpg'
];

const main = async () => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('cv').getContext('2d'),
    baseImg = await loadImage(imageUrls[0]),
    gradImg = await loadImage(imageUrls[1]);

  draw(ctx, baseImg, gradImg);
};

/**
 * Loads an Image object via a Promise.
 * @param {String} url - Location of an image file
 * @return {Promise<Image>} Returns a promise that resolves to an Image.
 */
const loadImage = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
  img.addEventListener('error', reject);
  img.src = url;
});

/**
 * Draws an image, as a gradient applied to it, above another image.
 * @param {Image} baseImg - Image that is applied under the gradient
 * @param {Image} gradImg - Image to be applied as a gradient
 */
const draw = (ctx, baseImg, gradImg) => {
  const {width, height} = baseImg,
      originX = Math.floor(width / 2),
      originY = Math.floor(height / 2),
      radius = Math.min(originX, originY);

  const offScreen = document.createElement('canvas');
  offScreen.width = offScreen.height = width;
  const ctx2 = offScreen.getContext('2d');

  ctx2.drawImage(gradImg, 0, 0, width, height);
  const gradient = ctx2.createRadialGradient(originX, originY, 0, originX, originY, radius);

  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)');

  ctx2.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ctx.drawImage(baseImg, 0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0, width, height);
};

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: NB: `err => reject(err)` can be replaced with just `reject`

Comment: and `img => loadImage(img)` with `loadImage`.

Comment: FWIW, (and given there's only two images so `Array#map` and `Promise#all`) are overkill) these days I'd use `await` - `const src = await loadImage(image[0]); const dst = await loadImage(image[1]); draw(ctx, src, dst)`

Comment: @Alnitak I just wanted to load an array of images. :) But yeah, if I am always loading two images, I would `async` my function and `await` for them. I went ahead and updated it to use your suggestion. I also had the meaning of `src` and `dest` flipped... The dest (base image) is the that gets the `src` (gradient) applied to it.

Comment: they don't really either individually get the gradient applied to them - they effectively *both* do, it's just that one image will show through where the transparency gradient is 1, and the other when it's 0, and a proportional blend of the two in between.

Comment: your comments reveal a misunderstanding of the requirement.   The OP's original image link has been replaced, but the idea was to blend between two images with a specified gradient (in this case one that's hard coded as a radial gradient coming out from the center).   The `gradientImg` is *not* the applied gradient.

Comment: @Alnitak I updated the variable names and added jsdoc.