# Image gradient on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, gradient, html5-canvas

I would like to obtain a radial gradient effect on an image (`alpha = 1` in the middle and transparent on the edges).

Do you have any ideeas on how I could do that?

Comment: take a look at this post maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525874/createradialgradient-and-transparency

Comment: I can make radial gradients on circles, but I need it on images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking what you want to do is:

1. Draw the image
2. Draw a radial gradient over it, where the borders are transparent and the middle is opaque and using the `globalCompositeOperation` setting on the context to blend the transparency gradient with the image.

You can rather easily translate this into code: http://jsfiddle.net/W8Ywp/1/.

```
var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.src = 'http://www.netstate.com/states/'
        + 'symb/flowers/images/oklahoma_rose.jpg';

img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300); // Draw image

    // Create gradient, from middle to borders
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(150, 150, 0,
                                            150, 150, 150);

    // Opaque white in the middle
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');

    // Transparent white at the borders
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300); // Fill rectangle over image with the gradient
};
```

Comment: This is not the solution I want. I want to add the image over another image, so it blends smoothly. If I make the gradient from white tranparent to white opaque, the image will have the gradient, but it will not be transparent on the edges, it will be white.

Comment: @gabitzish playing with http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-globalcompositeoperation the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` setting might fix that.

Comment: @Alnitak: You ought to post this as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @pimvdb - no matter, I've hit the rep cap for today anyway. In any event, I couldn't figure out from the docs just which value would actually work!  Why don't you fix yours instead? ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak: Because it was your idea and I didn't want to steal it :) I will update it in a while.

Comment: I believe @Alnitak's idea is incorrect.  The global compositing operation does not allow you to apply a gradient to an image.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320417/is-it-possible-to-make-a-gradient-transparent-layer-masking-image-using-canvas in which one answer had to resort to pixel-by-pixel manipulation of the canvas to achieve the requested effect.

Comment: @Nathan perhaps - all I know is that the OP said it was what he needed.

Comment: @Nathan setting the `globalCompositeOperation` to `destination-out` allows this to work exactly as the OP requested - see `http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/jtexo5es/  the image becomes more and more transparent (showing the green div underneath) towards the edges.

Comment: @Alnitak No.  You're adding a solid color on top of the image.  The OP explicitly states in the first comment on this very answer that he/she wants to add one image on top of another.  That's not what your fiddle does, nor can I see how `globalCompositeOperation` can accomplish that in general.

Comment: no, the image is on top of the color, that in this case happens to be solid, but is in the div underneath.  That div could contain anything.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jtexo5es/3/ for a new one where the rose is overlayed with a gradient transparency on top of another flower.

Comment: @Nathan care to take back your incorrect assertions, yet?

Comment: @Alnitak No need to be testy, I just want an answer to the OP's question.  I definitely take back my claim that you were putting color **on** the image; you're right, it's the other way around.  But I **still** claim you haven't answered the question.  You've just put an empty canvas on top of a background image, then put one image on the canvas.  The OP wants (and I want) a method for putting an image with a transparent gradient on a nonempty canvas.  If I try to adapt your solution to do so, I don't see how...here's my attempt for you to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/rfdjoh31/1/

Comment: @Nathan Not sure that's what this OP wanted, but in practise I think it would be necessary to create an off-screen canvas to create the "top" image modulated by the gradient alpha channel, and then composite the image data from that onto the (on-screen) canvas that already has the "bottom" image on it.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/rfdjoh31/4/

Comment: Excellent @Alnitak thank you!  That should be the marked-correct answer on this post and on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320417/is-it-possible-to-make-a-gradient-transparent-layer-masking-image-using-canvas/11757560?noredirect=1#comment45736276_11757560 as well.  I love it, thanks!

Comment: @Nathan I've added this is an answer to the other question.

Comment: @Alnitak I up-voted it and commented on the accepted answer that people should look at yours since it's faster and simpler.  Thanks again for it!