# Reflection of whole div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `div` and I want to add a reflection effect to it.

I know there are lots of tutorials for adding reflection to an image (like [**this**](http://www.xhtml-lab.com/css/create-reflection-effect-using-css3) and [**this**](http://designshack.net/articles/css/mastering-css-reflections-in-webkit/)), but I didn't find anything about reflecting whole div.

Is it possible with CSS3? And what about jQuery? How?

**EDIT**
[**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmGfK/) is what I tried according to the first tutorial. Also, If I use this method, user will have to download the reflected content twice, which is not good...

Comment: Seeing the first link states creating reflection with css3 even with code shown how it is done, I'd say yes, it is possible in CSS3. Have you tried implementing that example?

Comment: I have tried it, but the text was not reflected. I'll try again in jsfiddle

Comment: Can you post the relevant html/css or even the fiddle? It would propably be easier then to get a handle on it. Also the sample as far as I could see was reflecting images, not sure it will work with plain text the same way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using CSS3's `transform` property with `scaleY(-1)`:

CSS:

```
div.reflection
{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    blah
</div>
<div class="reflection">
    blah
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UMEdU/1/

Comment: If you combine this with some jQuery and add some opacity this could really work

Comment: And how to add some gradient to that? (like this: http://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/wkreflections-10.jpg )

Comment: I have modified your code and it looks better now, also user will not have to download content twice: http://jsfiddle.net/UMEdU/2/ , but still I don't know how to add gradient to it...

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424840/image-gradient-on-html5-canvas) will help.